# Piping multiple lines into ssh

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, ssh

I have set my own app as the shell of a user at a remote host. My app reads from stdin and prints output to stdout.

If I do `ssh user@remotehost.com`, and enter multiple lines of text, the app works as expected.

However, if I do this:

```
ssh user@remotehost.com < file.txt
```

Then my tool only processes the first line, and then quits.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suspect your application. Is it trying to write `STDERR` and failing? Does it log anything? How does it buffer its input? (If the answer is "not at all", then the rest of your input arrives while the app isn't listening). What system is the "remote host"?

This works for me:

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ seq 1 4 >14.txt; ssh localhost <14.txt
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
walt@localhost's password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-58-generic x86_64)

-bash: line 1: 1: command not found
-bash: line 2: 2: command not found
-bash: line 3: 3: command not found
-bash: line 4: 4: command not found
```

Perhaps you could use `expect`, or one of its variants:

```
walt@bat:~(127)$ apt-cache search expect | grep -w expect
empty-expect - Run processes and applications under pseudo-terminal
expect - Automates interactive applications
expect-lite - quick and easy command line automation tool
libjs-expect.js - behavior driven test assertions - JavaScript library
libnet-scp-expect-perl - Wrapper for scp to send passwords via Expect
libtest-expect-perl - module for automated driving and testing of terminal-based programs
node-expect.js - behavior driven test assertions - Node.js module
tcl-expect - Automates interactive applications (Tcl package)
tcl-expect-dev - Automates interactive applications (development)
```